# Using the Schema.org types 'Organization', 'LocalBusiness' and 'LegalService' simultaneously for a law firm

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I created a JSON-LD schema for a law firm website. I've checked this code in Google Structured Data Testing Tool and there is no errors. But no syntax errors does not mean that the schema is good.

Can I use `Organization`, `LocalBusiness` and `LegalService` as type simultaneously?

```json
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@graph": [
  {
    "@type": [
      "Organization",
      "LocalBusiness",
      "LegalService"
    ],
"@id": "https://example.com/#legalservice",
"name": "Webiste name example",
"description": "Webiste description example",
"priceRange": "$$",
"url": "https://example.com/",
"logo": {
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "@id": "https://example.com/#logo",
  "url": "https://example.com/logo.png",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 80,
  "caption": "Website name"
},
"image": {
  "@id": "https://example.com/#logo"
},
"telephone": "+00000000000",
"email": "email@example.com",
"hasMap": "http://maps.google.com/example",
"address": {
  "@type": "PostalAddress",
  "addressLocality": "Example city",
  "addressRegion": "Example state",
  "postalCode": "Example postal code",
  "streetAddress": "Example street"
},
"sameAs": [
  "http://facebook.com/exampleProfile",
  "http://twitter.com/exampleProfile"
],
"openingHours": "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr, 09:00-17:00"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By definition, every `LocalBusiness` is also an `Organization`, and every `LegalService` is also a `LocalBusiness`.

Schema.org types inherit all their parent types:

- [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness):

  > `Thing` > `Organization` > `LocalBusiness`
- [`LegalService`](https://schema.org/LegalService):

  > `Thing` > `Organization` > `LocalBusiness` > `LegalService`

So there is usually no need to specify the parent types in addition.

There is one case where it can be useful: if a consumer (like Google Search) doesn’t yet recognize a new type, it can make sense to provide the new unrecognized type in addition to the nearest recognized parent type. But if the type is correctly recognized, there is no benefit in providing its parent types in addition.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help ;) And what do you think about the rest of code? Is it properly?

Comment: @troxxx: Ths is not the right place to answer this :) I would suggest: 1) if you have more specific questions about a single aspect, post another question (and only show the code that is relevant for this aspect). 2) if you want a general code review, you can try asking on [codereview.se] (I’m not 100 % sure if reviewing the Schema.org structure is on-topic there, but reviewing the JSON-LD is).

Comment: uhh.. it's complicated because there is no topics about schema.org on Code Review ;/ There are even no tags about seo, structured-data etc. So i see there is no appropriate place to ask about schema org code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will allow myself to give an answer in terms of a Google vision. Check the following **[Google guidelines for the type LocalBusiness](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business#local_business_properties)**:

> Use the most specific LocalBusiness sub-type possible; for example,
>   Restaurant, DaySpa, HealthClub, and so on.

Thus, it may be beneficial for a law firm to use a top-level type such as **LegalService**. However, it is worth paying attention to the fact that this type also has two more specifying types such as **Attorney** and **Notary**.

Using the most specific type will help users in their searches and can increase organic traffic to your website. Users who are looking for legal services can easily find your website if it has markup for the top-level type **LegalServices**. However, this may not be so easy when markup for type **Organization** or **LocalBusiness**. In this case, there will be a multitude of organizations and local businesses in SERP, among which your law firm may be lost. When specifying a type, for example for the type Notary, it will be in the SERP when searching for a notary.

Comment: Thank you for help. But Attorney type is already deprecated.

Comment: Actually, I focused my answer not on specific types, but on the general trend for legal form data.